# Equi-consistency of inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I have trouble understanding this wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_statements_independent_of_ZFC), concerning inaccessible cardinals.

First "These statements are strong enough to imply the consistency of ZFC". I guess what they mean by that is if $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal, then $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC, where $V$ is the Von Neumann hierarchy.

Then they argue that a proof in ZFC, assuming ZFC is consistent, of the consistency of ZFC+$\kappa$ is impossible. Because it would prove the consistency of ZFC, violating Gödel's incompleteness theorem.

I don't understand this, I imagine a relative consistency proof would rather be a model transformation : given a model of ZFC as input, produce a model of ZFC+$\kappa$ as output. Then we could continue producing $V_\kappa$ to get another model of ZFC. Where is the contradiction in that ? To me it seems we first assumed a model of ZFC, then produced another one. ZFC didn't produce a model of itself from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the incompleteness theorem to $ZFC+\exists \text{an inaccessible} $

Comment: So simple... sorry I didn't see that myself